# Azure Storage account opening issue

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an RBAC access to Azure portal. Previously I was able to access storage account and blobs successfully. But suddenly I am unable to access container or blob. I am able to view the storage account listed for me, but cannot access it.
I get error as **"Something went wrong while getting your resources. Please try again later."**   I tried refreshing, clearing cache and signing again. Still facing same issue.
[image]

In portal I get notification as **"Refresh the browser to try again.
Microsoft_Azure_Storage extension failed to load"**

[image]

There is no network issue, as I can access all other resources from portal at same point. 
Also there is no Unauthorized access issue notification.

Unable to figure out what is the issue.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Change a browser to have a try.

Comment: If you are still facing this issue, I recommand that you could [create a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get deep help from Azure team.

Comment: Was the provided below answer helpful for you @Amruta ?

Comment: In my case the issue is occurring only when I am running a browser (Chrome) on specific servers. Everything works fine from my PC. That tells me its not an RBAC issue, and more likely some security restriction / proxy server issue when browsing from specific servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend checking the **activity logs** for recent RBAC changes in case if they happened and someone changed access to containers/blobs, here's how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/change-history-report

I'd also recommend checking the **list of roles/access** you currently have by following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/change-history-report

If you are still experiencing the issue, in case if you have a co-admin, check if they are facing the same issues. if they are, please send me your subscription ID, link to this thread, and include attn Adam in the subject to AzCommunity[at]microsoft.com ? 
I'll enable a free support ticket to quickly escalate it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I am not facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue while I was using VPN from Bangladesh. When I disconnected from the VPN, it works fine.